# console.log(this.props) undefined

Tags: reactjs

In my code, I console.log(this.props) inside componentDidMount while I got undefined. I console.log(this.props) inside render() I got four outputs, for the first two all the properties are undefined, the last two are correct.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        const { ratingsAverage } = this.props;
        console.log(ratingsAverage);
        //this.setState({value: this.props.ratingsAverage})
    }

render() {
        console.log(this.props);
 }
```

the output of console.log(ratingsAverage) inside componentDidMount() is undefined.

the output of console.log(this.props) inside render() is on the pic below

[image]

Comment: componentDidMount gets called only once and at that time your props might be undefined if they are coming through an asynchronous method. Whereas render gets executed everytime props are changed. Everything seems working normal. What's the problem you are facing here?

Comment: My problem is how could I get the props inside a componentDidMount in child component?

Answer (score 0):

Try this . your component constructor should be like this

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     //states
  };
}
```